# Is it possible to show UAC dialog for one thread in application?

Tags: c#, wpf, security

I have a method and want to run it with new thread with admin privilege,

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = @"BUILTIN\Administrators")]
    void Install()
    {
      //do some thing
    }
```

I run it in this way,

```
installerTh = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Install));
        installerTh.Name = "Installer";
        installerTh.Start();
```

but it gives me error

> System.Security.SecurityException was unhandled
>
> Message=Request for principal permission failed.

Any Idea to show UAC window before running this thread ? (or in the middle of running Process )

Comment: have you seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533/request-windows-vista-uac-elevation-if-path-is-protected

Comment: Hi Daniel , they explain how to start new privileged process,I want to give privilege to my current running Thread or Process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UAC is all or nothing. You cannot apply a UAC prompt to a single thread, only to a process. What you need to do is launch your application with a special command line using UAC, and the command line will let you know to start the thread you want. It does not have to be a command line, you could use any type of IPC to let the spawned process know to run the thread. I wrote an answer about launching a process under UAC [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925065/correct-way-to-deal-with-uac-in-c-sharp/3925167#3925167).

You might also want to consider getting a code signing certificate so that the UAC dialog won't keep saying "Unknown" as the publisher.

**Update:** Based on your comment above, you also cannot apply UAC to your process currently running, only to a new process.

Comment: Thanks dear Matthew,I are you sure only new process ? there is no way for running one,  because VS.NET needs to restart when wants to do sth that needs privileged access.