# Windows 10 Tablet mode: startup tasks does not start in foreground

Tags: uwp, windows-10, desktop-bridge

I'm trying to automatically launch an UWP (Electron-based) application when the user logs in, so I've defined a StartupTask in the AppxManifest.xml like it is explained in [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-extensions#executable%22prova%22) from Microsoft.

While this solution works as expected when Tablet Mode is off, if the user logs in with Tablet Mode enabled the application is executed, but Start Menu remains in foreground and covers my application.

Is there a way to obtain this behavior, or to force my application to gain foreground, or to enable/disable Tablet mode (in order to enable Tablet mode after the application started)?

Comment: Personalization > Start > Set "Use start full screen" to "off".

Comment: Nothing chances: still starting in background (either if set to off or on the Start Menù si displayed fullscreen)

Comment: Oh, that turned out to be a bug: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/2867

Comment: What looks strange to me is also the fact that if I'm trying to start an application which requires elevation (e.g. Services) the UAC dialog pops up then the application starts in background too. Maybe there is some bug also in Windows, I cannot find a valid explanation for this behavior.

Comment: Applications have several threads, and only one of them awaits for UAC consent. GUI doesn't need any privileges. I think everything's fine.

Comment: [Well, that's embarassing.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939017/is-it-possible-to-show-uac-dialog-for-one-thread-in-application)

Comment: From the user-experience perspective IMHO is horrible. You search for "Services" application from Start Menu, you click on it, UAC pops over Start Menu, you authorize elevation and as a result you're still facing the Start Menu. If you want to proceed you have to click on Task View in order to find the opened Service application and give it focus. It looks like Start Menu tries always to get focus back.

Comment: Yes, that's why I keep my system at Windows 7, and going to migrate to Linux when its support is over. Microsoft has broken UX of their most popular product.