# C# Get administrative privileges for the current process

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I want to ask for Admin Privileges (UAC) for the current (already running) process because it has already processed some data for example, I don't want to run it as admin just to re-do the stuff I did before. How can I achieve this?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secbp/running-with-administrator-privileges

Comment: Privileges are set when the process is started, and cannot be changed afterwards. You need a new process, but you can send the new process all the data that you have already processed, through some inter-process communication (usually a pipe, but also a database). I remember some COM interface that is supposed to help with all this, but at the moment I have no more details about it.

Comment: @Dialecticus Privileges are set per thread. A thread can impersonate the security context of a different user.

Comment: @IInspectable So are you saying that it is possible to do what the questions asks to do? Because I was under the impression that it was not possible.

Comment: *"So are you saying that it is possible to do what the questions asks to do?"* - No. I'm saying that the security context is evaluated for the calling thread. Whether there is a (documented) way to adjust privileges as required by the question I do not know.

Comment: @IInspectable this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7939017/395718) suggests that you can't make the UAC prompt appear for a thread.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thread can impersonate in case it have `SeImpersonatePrivilege` but not admin usually have no such privilege - it filtered. so even if code in process some how got elevated/system token - it anyway can not impersonate it. so by dessign it impossible. need start new process or use local server com object for some operations

Comment: @IInspectable Good to clear that up that this was an aside not related to the question asked

Comment: you can not do exactly what you, if you have no SeImpersonatePrivilege , and by default you have not it. maximum what you can - run second, elevated instance, as server, for handle some request from not elevated instance . really for what you need "admin" ? usually only for create/open some files or registry keys. not more. so you can delegate this job via IPC to elevated instance, while processing data and show ui in initial process. of course not simply solution, but for simply need request uac on process start